# PowerMockito not allowing access to private method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have the below classes:

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FlexComm.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationContext.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Processor.class, FlexComm.class,...})
public class ProcessorTest {
    @Autowired
    Cache cache;
    @Autowired
    Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    FlexComm flex;

     @Before
     public void init() {
         flex = PowerMockito.mock(FlexComm.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorValid() {
        try {
            
            String req = "{\"version\":\"1\",\"data\":\"encryptedData\"}";
            byte[] requestToBytes = req.getBytes();
            String url = "https://someurl";
            String resp = "{\"type\":\"CHECKOUT\",\"id\":\"hostid\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"error\":\"\"}";
            byte[] responseToBytes = resp.getBytes();
            String payload = "{\"source\":\"HQVNMTBVK\",\"id\":\"hostid\",\"auditValue\":2986,\"requestData\":[{\"featureName\":\"name\",\"featureVersion\":\"1.0\",\"count\":1,\"flags\":0}]}";
         
            PowerMockito.doReturn(responseToBytes).when(flex, "talkToServer", Byte[].class, String.class);
            
            RequestData reqData = new RequestData("1", Tools.encryptString(payload));
            CompletableFuture<ResponseData> response = processor.processRequest(reqData);
            assertEquals("SUCCESS", response.getStatus("status"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Class I'm testing:

```
@Configuration
public class Processor {
    @Autowired
    private FlexComm flex;

    @Autowired
    Cache cache;

    public void processRequest() {
        //does some logic then calls below method
        doCheckOut();
    }
    private ResponseData doCheckOut() {
        //more logic, then calls the public flex method
        ReturnData rd = flex.checkOut();
    }
}
```

Class with private method I'm trying to access

```
@Configuration
public class FlexComm {

    public ReturnData checkOut() {
        return doFlexComm();
    }

    private ReturnData doFlexComm() {
        LicenseManager licenseManager = createLicenseManager() //imported class
        
        byte[] requestData = null;
        byte[] responseData = null;
        //more logic, too much code to include here
        requestData = licenseManager.getRequestData();
        responseData = talkToServer(requestData); //this is the method I want to call
        return new ReturnData(requestData, responseData);   
    }

    private byte[] talkToServer(byte[] requestData) {
        Comm comm = getHttpInstance();
        byte[] responseData = sendBinaryRequest(comm, requestData);
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mock the talkToServer method, but PowerMockito keeps saying that it can't be accessed because it is a private method. I also can't change any of the source code because it is too tightly bound together, so any changes could easily break something. I've scoured the web for an answer, and I've tried every variation of `PowerMockito.doReturn().when()` and `PowerMockito.when().thenReturn()`, but have had no luck. At this point I'm really just looking to see if there is something obviously wrong with how my code is set up, or if what I'm doing is actually possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I  know this isn't really an answer per se, but I think using PowrMockito to mock private methods is a last resort option, when your code isn't under your control. But when it is, I'd change the code to make it more testable, for example by delegating the `talkToServer` method to a separate class, and mock/stub that code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've replaced `flex` with a mock, you can't expect any of the methods of `FlexComm` to run for that mock, unless you explicitly tell them to do that.  So the `processRequest` method won't actually call `doFlexComm` at all.

You probably want to use a Spy instead of a Mock, which is an object that you can stub, whose methods actually call real methods on a real object by default.  I've never tried using Spy objects with PowerMock, but there are examples online which I'm sure you can find.